# Select only one term_id from taxonomy

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a custom post type and a taxonomy, where I can put more the one value to the taxonomy, in this case the taxonomy is the city. I want to make a query that the result is the posts that only have ONE value set. Example: I want all posts that the taxnomy is only "term_id = 3" that is "sao-paulo-sp".

But I have some posts that has more than one value set to it, like "sao-paulo-sp, city 2, city 3 city 4, etc" and this kinda of post keep showing up in my results.

```
SELECT wp.ID, wp.post_title, wt.term_id  FROM wp_posts wp  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = 
wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)
WHERE wtt.taxonomy = 'cities'
AND wt.slug = 'sao-paulo-sp'
ORDER BY wp.ID
```

I would like that the result was the posts that only have "sao-paulo-sp" or "term_id = 3' as his value to the taxonomy cities

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT wp.ID, wp.post_title, wt.term_id
FROM wp_posts wp INNER JOIN
     wp_term_relationships wtr
     ON wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id` INNER JOIN
     wp_term_taxonomy wtt
     ON wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id` INNER JOIN 
     wp_terms wt
     ON wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`
WHERE wtt.taxonomy = 'cities'
GROUP BY wp.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(wt.slug) = 'sao-paulo-sp'
ORDER BY wp.ID;
```

I am not sure what `wt.term_id` is doing in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

Srry, my english was not good enough to specify my question, if help anyone I solved my problem doing a NOT IN in a select that has term_id different than tem_id 3.

```
SELECT wp.ID, wp.post_title, wt.slug
   FROM wp_posts wp
   INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`
   INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = 
   wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`
WHERE wtt.taxonomy = 'cidades'
AND wp.ID NOT IN
    (SELECT wp.ID
    FROM wp_posts wp
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = 
    wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`
    WHERE wtt.taxonomy ='cidades' and wtt.term_id <> 3)
ORDER BY wp.ID
```